# JSON not mapped to Class

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core 3.0 application with WebPages and I try to send a JSON via ajax to my handler. But the parameter is always null or just filled with the default values. I tried to if the JSON string from the post is parseable and it works when I parse manually.

This is my controller:

```
    public void OnPost([FromBody]FilterModel filter)
    {
        Console.Write(filter);
    }
```

This is the model class:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public DateTime TimeRangeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeRangeTo { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The ajax request:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/CustomerOverview/Test",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            CustomerId: customerId,
                            TimeRangeFrom: picker.startDate,
                            TimeRangeTo: picker.endDate
                        }),
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            button.hide();
                        },
                        failure: function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
```

And the JSON as logged in Chrome Dev Tools:

```
{CustomerId: "1", TimeRangeFrom: "2019-08-26T22:00:00.000Z", TimeRangeTo: "2019-09-25T21:59:59.999Z"}
```

Do I have to setup a mapping or something?

Comment: Did you fill the form data in the view and want to pass it with json format by using ajax?If so,you must convert it to json object like what you did.Due to `FromBody` attribute receives json by default.

Answer (score 1):

`FromBody` attribute  will parse the model the default way which in most cases are sent by the content type `application/json` from the request body.So if you fill a form and pass the form data to the controller action,you need to convert the JavaScript object into a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

`FromForm` attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type application/x-www-url-formencoded.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#sources

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it can't convert an "1" to an int. I had to convert the value for customerId to a int first so that I have this JSON:

```
{
    "CustomerId": 1, 
    "TimeRangeFrom": "2019-08-26T22:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeRangeTo": "2019-09-25T21:59:59.999Z"
}
```